# Capture snmpwalk output via powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, snmp

I would like to run a program and save its output into a file. The program starts, I see a cmd window pop-up, but the file is alway empty. I tryed these versions:

```
start snmpwalk.exe "parameters will be here" >text.txt
start snmpwalk.exe "parameters will be here" 2>&1 | out-file text.txt
```

Can you help me how to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can even WALK directly in PowerShell by loading #SNMP Library, http://vwiki.co.uk/SNMP_and_PowerShell which gives you more flexibility sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `start`, you should be able to just use the command as normal from within powershell.

A slightly more powershell way would be to use `invoke-expression`

```
invoke-expression "snmpwalk [parameters]" | out-file text.text
```

Comment: thanks. It's works now. The right command is: invoke-expression ".\snmpwalk [parameters]" | out-file text.text